# Conservation of a specific type of charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

The Law of Conservation of Charge states that 'the total charge in an isolated system is conserved.' Can we say that total negative and positive charges (individually) in an isolated system is conserved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the positive and negative charges are not conserved separately.
There are many processes in particle physics
where positive and negative charges are created newly,
or where positive and negative charges are annihilated.

Some examples:

- The [radioactive decay of a free neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron#Free_neutron_decay)
  $$n \to p^+ + e^- + \bar{\nu}$$
- The [annihilation of an electron-positron pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron%E2%80%93positron_annihilation)
  $$e^- + e^+ \to \gamma + \gamma$$
- The [creation of an electron-positron pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Photon_to_electron_and_positron)
  $$\gamma + \text{nucleus} \to e^- + e^+ + \text{nucleus}$$
- The creation of particles in high-energy collisions
  (like for example in the [Large Hadron Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_Hadron_Collider))
  $$p^+ + p^- \to \text{many positive and negative particles}$$

So, in general only the total charge (positive + negative) is conserved.